# how to construct SQL pivot table with recursive query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table, dynamic-sql

Imagine I have these tables

WorkOrder:

```
[Id], [ServiceId], [StatusId]
```

Service <-- self-referencing table

```
[Id], [SName], [SCode], [SDnaCode], [SerivceParentId:Nullable]
```

Status

```
[Id], [StName], [StCode]
```

Now how do I get a pivot table results like this:

```
|StName   |RootService_1|RootService_2|...
+---------+-------------+-------------+----
|Initiated|23           |12           |...
|Closed   |8            |5            |...
```

Keep in mind that the count-numbers are for root service and it's own hierarchy per root service

Example records in `[Service]` table

```
|ID|SName        |SCode|SDnaCode|SerivceParentId|
+--+-------------+-----+--------+---------------+
| 1|RootService_1|RS01 |RS01    |NULL           |
| 2|RS01_Child_1 |C01  |RS01.C01|1              |
| 3|RS01_Child_2 |C02  |RS01.C02|1              |
| 4|RootService_2|RS02 |RS02    |NULL           |
| 5|RS02_Child_1 |C01  |RS02.C01|2              |
| 6|RS02_Child_2 |C02  |RS02.C02|2              |
```

So the number `23` in the example pivot table under `RootService_1` is the count of `Initiated WorkOrder`s which has `ServiceId` either 1,2 or 3 combined

Keep in mind that I want to wrap it in dynamic SQL in order to generate values for pivot table `for clause`.

I hope I explained my question well, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution tho i was hoping for a one with less-text-data dependent 
this solution depends on the `SDnaCode` column which is `ServiceDnaCode` in my situation and i made it a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DashboardGetServicesDataByStatus @lvl int, @parentId  NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE 
    @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', 
    @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @sqlCommand nvarchar(max)=''; 

-- select the StatusName
set @sqlCommand = 'SELECT 
    @columns+=QUOTENAME(
    (SELECT value from string_split(ServiceDnaCode,''.'')
order by CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
OFFSET      @lvl rows
fetch next 1 rows only)) + '',''
FROM 
    [Service] where ParentServiceId' + 
        case
            when @lvl>0 then ' IN(@parentId)'
            else    ' is null '
        end
    + '
ORDER BY 
    Id;';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@lvl int,@parentId NVARCHAR(max),@columns NVARCHAR(max) OUTPUT'
, @lvl = @lvl,@parentId=@parentId, @columns=@columns OUTPUT

-- remove the last comma
SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);

print @columns
print @lvl

-- construct dynamic SQL
SET @sql ='
with cte_service as (
select * from [Service] where [Service].Id IN ('+CAST(@parentId as varchar(max))+')
union all
select e.* from [Service] e inner join cte_service o on e.ParentServiceId= o.Id
)

SELECT * FROM (
select count(wo.Id) ID,os.StatusName STATENAME ,
(SELECT value from string_split(ServiceDnaCode,''.'')
order by CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
OFFSET      '+CAST(@lvl as varchar(max))+' rows
fetch next 1 rows only) SNAME from WorkOrder wo 
left join RefWorkOrderStatus os on wo.OrderStatusCode=os.Id 
left join [Service] s on wo.MainServiceId=s.Id
where wo.MainServiceId IN (select Id from cte_service)
group by os.StatusName,s.ServiceDnaCode
) t
pivot(
sum(ID)
for SNAME IN ('+ @columns +')
) as pivottable';

-- execute the dynamic SQL
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;

END
Go
```